# Make Emacs-style shortcuts behave differently than arrow keys.

Tags: macos, emacs, cocoa, keybindings

This is a bit of a weird question, I'll admit, but this is something that really annoys me. I have come to rely on the Emacs shortcuts (mainly <kbd>ctrl ^</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl ^</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl ^</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, and <kbd>ctrl ^</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) and the behavior of <kbd>ctrl ^</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl ^</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> is very different than in Emacs. With Emacs, going up a line will ignore soft wrapping and go to the next actual line, not the next displayed line. I've just gotten used to it, I guess. Is there any way to make the Cocoa/Emacs up and down keybindings behave like the real Emacs (preferably only <kbd>ctrl ^</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl ^</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, not the arrow keys)?

Comment: As of Emacs 23.1: ** The C-n and C-p line-motion commands now move by screen lines,
taking continued lines and variable-width characters into account.
Setting `line-move-visual' to nil reverts this to the previous
behavior (i.e., motion by logical lines based on buffer contents
alone).

Comment: @AlanShutko Heh, I guess I haven't updated Emacs in a while, I'm usually using the command line version anyway. Maybe if I update I'll get used to it.

Comment: I'll admit, I set line-move-visual back to nil because I was used to the old way too! I just found it amusing.

Comment: @AlanShutko amusing?

Comment: Amusing that you want OS X to act like Emacs, when Emacs recently changed to act like OS X.

Comment: @AlanShutko I guess :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any way to do that in [DefaultKeyBinding.dict](http://osxnotes.net/keybindings.html).

For example `selectLine:` selects a wrapped or visual line and `selectParagraph:` selects a non-wrapped or hard line, but I couldn't find methods for moving a non-wrapped line up or down.

One thing you can do is to make command-delete and command-forward delete act on non-wrapped lines:

```
{
  "@\U007F" = deleteToBeginningOfParagraph:;
  "@\UF728" = deleteToEndOfParagraph:;
}
```

You can't remap command-left or command-right, so for example this doesn't work:

```
{
  "@\Uf700" = moveToBeginningOfParagraph:;
  "@\Uf701" = moveToEndOfParagraph:;
}
```

Comment: I wasn't expecting anything... oh well...